# How to render a task in a table cell when a user submits the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u749668864_PandaHost";
$password = "Effy1234";
$dbname = "u749668864_PandaHost";

$q = $_REQUEST["task"];
$task = $q;
echo $task;

$conn->close();
?>
```

I've started looking at ajax and I'm really confused how to render a task when
the user submits this form. I've already created a html table and then added
the cells with javascript. When the user clicks the form, I want them to
submit a task and their duration, and then see the task displayed below the
submit button.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table id="table"> <!-- table -->
    <th colspan="7" id="month"></th>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
<script>
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
// check current month
      var month = new Date();
      var Allmonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      for (var i = 0; i < Allmonths.length; i++) {
        if (month.getMonth() == i) {
          document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = Allmonths[i];
        }
      };
// start creating cells
      var row;
      var cell;
      var date = 1;
      var newDate = 1;
      var i;
      var j;
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
          cell = row.insertCell(-1);
          var newI = i;
          var newJ = j;
          if (newI >= 4 && newJ >= 3) {
            cell.className = "grey-cell";
            cell.innerHTML = newDate;
            newDate++;
          }
          else {
            cell.className = "cell";
            cell.innerHTML = date;
            date++;
          }
        };
      };
// on clicking a cell, display a form, and then render the task on submission
      $("td").click(function(event){
          var box = $("<div>").html(
            "<form>" +
            "<label for=task>" +
            "<input type=text id=task name=task placeholder=Task>" +
            "</label>" +
            "<label for=duration>" +
            "<input type=number id=duration name=duration placeholder=Duration>" +
            "</label>" +
            "<button id=add type=submit>Add Task</button>" +
            "</form>" +
            "<p id=task></p>"
          )
        $(this).append(box);
        $("#add").click(function(){
          $("#task").load("tasks.php #task", function(responseTxt){
            $(this).html(responseTxt)
          });
        });
      })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wires are getting a little crossed here. When you create your input form inside of the table cell that has the number, your click event on the cell is applied to the form elements. Better to have that form appear outside of your click event. I moved it to it's own div. To see the results of the form, you have to `preventDefault()` on the submit button to prevent the page from refreshing. Then you can append a 'tasks' div with the values from your form

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
// check current month
var month = new Date();
var Allmonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
for (var i = 0; i < Allmonths.length; i++) {
  if (month.getMonth() == i) {
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = Allmonths[i];
  }
};
// start creating cells
var row;
var cell;
var date = 1;
var newDate = 1;
var i;
var j;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    var newI = i;
    var newJ = j;
    if (newI >= 4 && newJ >= 3) {
      cell.className = "date-cell grey-cell";
      cell.innerHTML = newDate;
      newDate++;
    } else {
      cell.className = "date-cell cell";
      cell.innerHTML = date;
      date++;
    }
  };
};
// on clicking a cell, display a form, and then render the task on submission
$("td.date-cell").click(function(event) {
  $("#create-task").html(
    "<form>" +
    "<label for=task>" +
    "<input type=text id=task name=task placeholder=Task>" +
    "</label>" +
    "<label for=duration>" +
    "<input type=number id=duration name=duration placeholder=Duration>" +
    "</label>" +
    "<button id=add type=submit>Add Task</button>" +
    "</form>" +
    "<p id=task></p>"
  )
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    // prevent the page reload
    e.preventDefault();
    // get data 
    let duration = $('#duration').val()
    let task = $('#task').val()
    $('#tasks').append(`<li>Task: ${task}, duration: ${duration}</li>`)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <!-- table -->
  <th colspan="7" id="month"></th>
</table>
<div id='create-task'></div>
<ul id='tasks'></ul>
```